# Trouble Installing MathTimes Pro 2 (MacTex)

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, mactex

I recently obtained the MathTimes Pro 2 font from PCTex, and I'm having some trouble getting it to work; I use MacTex 2010.

I've blindly followed the instructions posted on PCTex here: http://www.pctex.com/kb/74.html

However, when I attempt to use the package, I get the following error message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls

Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty)
(./Fonts.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdft
ex.map}] (./Fonts.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 mt2syt
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mt2syt.
mktexpk: perhaps mt2syt is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file mt2syt): Font mt2syt at 600 not found

 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I've searched relentlessly for a solution, but I can't seem to find one (or make one work). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without the exact same system and the files from PCtex. However, it sounds to me as though something went wrong when you ran `updmap-sys`. Try running `updmap-sys` again, this time without any options. Look for mentions of `mtpro2.map` in the output. What do you find?

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem did have something to do with the updmap-sys command. I had to copy the .map file, in this case mtpro2.map, to the folder /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c. I'm still not entirely sure why this fixed the problem; I just played around with a few commands while looking at http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php?title=Font_Installation.

Comment: It sounds like my question was poorly posed; what is the proper etiquette if I've found the solution? Should I delete the question or post my answer?

Comment: In situations like this, where you asked a genuine question and then happened to find the answer yourself, it's perfectly acceptable to post your own answer and accept it. Although the problem was specific to your system and the font files that you purchased, other users may find the discussion of `updmap-sys` useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you should not copy the map file to the `web2c` directory. `web2c` is for use of configure files, for example `updmap-local.cfg`.

Usually map files go to `fonts/map` or `fonts/map/dvips`.

Your original problem seems to be that you didn't run `mktexlsr` before updating the `updmap` database. This caused the `updmap` cannot find the required map file. I don't know if `texhash` has any effect today though it is suggested in the PCTeX's website.

Anyway, you solved the problem yourself, and I think it is because as long as `updmap` can find the the map file, either in `fonts/map`, where it should be, or in `web2c`, it is ok. But it is still better to keep files where they are supposed to be. See the documentation for [TDS](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/tds/tds.html).

Just a tip may be useful. I create a file `updmap-local.cfg` in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c` which contains the name of the map files in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map`. Since I got quite a few fonts installed in `texmf-local`, it is more convenient to keep a record of all map files. If say, I reinstalled the MacTeX, and the `/usr/local/texlive/2010` folder is completely overwritten. All I need to do is

```
sudo mktexlsr
sudo tlmgr generate updmap
sudo updmap-sys
```

As long as my `texmf-local` folder does not change. Thus I don't have to type `udpmap-sys --enable ...` where `...` can get quite long and error prone.